# Помогите!!! Делаю простой сайт , запускаю в chrome видно сам код

Tags: html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>my site</title>
        <meta chrset="utf-8">
        <meta name="keywords" content="мой сайт,html,my site">
        <meta name="description" content="мой сайт,html,help people">
    </head>
    <body>
    
</body>
```

Comment: первое, что хочется узнать - какое расширение у файла?

Comment: у файла index.html, пишу в sublime text.

Comment: Я уверен, что это не index.html, а index.html.txt - включите отображение расширений в проводнике (я почему-то полагаю, что у вас Windows).

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!

Comment: Для начала приведите код к такому состоянию: `<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <meta charset="utf-8"> <meta name="keywords" content="мой сайт,html,my site"> <meta name="description" content="мой сайт,html,help people"> <title>my site</title> </head> <body> </body> </html>`
P.s. charset у Вас написано с ошибкой и нет закрывающего тега html
И проверьте, включено ли у Вас на компьютере расширение html

Comment: @void, ответы - в ответы.

Comment: @Qwertiy, вынес в ответ, спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Я уверен, что это не `index.html`, а `index.html.txt` - включите отображение расширений в проводнике (я почему-то полагаю, что у вас Windows).